# Any way to detect whether an object of my class is create on stack?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

Now I need to detect whether my class is created as a stack/global/thread_local variable, for example:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() {
    if(im_on_stack) {
      std::cout << "I'm on stack" << std::endl;
    } else if(im_in_global) {
      std::cout << "I'm in global" << std::endl;
    } else if(im_a_thread_local) {
      std::cout << "I'm a thread_local" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "I'm on ohters location" << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

class Bar {
  Foo mFoo;
};

Foo gFoo;
thread_local Foo tFoo;
int main() {
  Foo lFoo;
}
```

and the out put should be:

```
I'm on ohters location
I'm in global
I'm a thread_local
I'm on stack
```

This there any way in C++ I can do this?

**Edit:**

why I'm doing this:
I'm writing a garbage collection library, and I got a class, let's call it `gc_ptr`, I need to know if this `gc_ptr` is a gc root (which is create on the location I mentioned) or not (which is a member of another class)

**Edit2**:

According to the concept of gc root, which is a reference which is not on a heap, I should probably asked in this way: can I detect if my class is create on the heap? But I think on heap or on stack make this question no difference.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? (Spoiler: you can't.) If you explain what problem you're attempting to solve by doing it, you might get some useful solutions to your actual problem.

Comment: Technically, the C++ specification doesn't say anything about local variables being on "the stack", it just describes the behavior, scopes and life-times of such variables. That compilers put local variables on the stack is an implementation-specific thing that just happens to be quite common.

Comment: Can be done to some extent: Assuming, you need it only for a certain kind of classes: You have to overload `new` (or wrap dynamic construction in a static create). You have to derive all considered classes from a base class with a specific constructor. To pass info from `new` to the constructor is a bit tricky. In our case, we used a global `set` where `new` remembered pointers to created instances and the corresponding constructor looked into it to determine whether creation was done by `new`. That was sufficient for us. (About the other topics - no idea...)

Comment: The "best known" GC for C and C++ is [the Boehm–Demers–Weiser collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector); you might get some ideas from there. It does not use the method you're suggesting, though. (You can't add this both reliably and transparently.)

Comment: Hi @Scheff, I'm not quite get you, do you have some examples? In my case, I only got one class which cannot be inherit, which is a data structure represent for a gc reference, seems quite fit the extent you said.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Not with standard C++. There may be compiler or OS specific solutions, but nothing portable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could make a heuristic to detect stack allocated objects by detecting in their constructor whether their address is close to a stack allocated variable. Assuming that the stack and the heap have completely different memory addresses it should work. Completely undefined behaviour though according to the standard. e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        int test = 0; // test is on the stack
        auto distance = reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(&test);
        isStack = std::abs(distance) < 1024; // completely arbitrary magic number, will need to experiment
    }

    bool isStack;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "stack: " << A().isStack << "\n";
    std::cout << "stack: " << std::make_unique<A>()->isStack << "\n";
}
```

I don't think you could expand this technique to thread local variables. You'd also need to take care in copy constructors and assignment operators to handle copying from a stack to a heap object and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is not part of the spec, so no.

If you told us on what system/os you are working, maybe we can assist - some systems may provide the stack address and size - usually this is available in embedded devices as part of the compiler output (the address), and as input (the size) as part of the environment/project configuration.

Comment: Hi, let say it's Linux for example, do you happen to know how to get heap address?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot say for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

What I wrote in my comment:

> Can be done to some extent: Assuming, you need it only for a certain kind of classes: You have to overload new (or wrap dynamic construction in a static create). You have to derive all considered classes from a base class with a specific constructor. To pass info from `new` to the constructor is a bit tricky. In our case, we used a global `set` where `new` remembered pointers to created instances and the corresponding constructor looked into it to determine whether creation was done by `new`. That was sufficient for us. (About the other topics - no idea...)

A demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Object {
  private:
    static thread_local std::set<void*> pNewSet;
    bool _isNewed;

  public:
    Object();
    Object(const Object&) = delete;
    const Object& operator=(const Object&) = delete;
    ~Object() = default;

    static void* operator new(size_t size);

    bool isNewed() const { return _isNewed; }

  private:
    static std::set<void*>& getNewPtrs()
    {
      static thread_local std::set<void*> pNewSet;
      return pNewSet;
    }
};

void* Object::operator new(size_t size)
{
  std::set<void*> &pNewSet = getNewPtrs();
  void *p = ::operator new(size);
  if (p) pNewSet.insert(p);
  return p;
}

Object::Object(): _isNewed(false)
{
  std::set<void*> &pNewSet = getNewPtrs();
  std::set<void*>::iterator iter = pNewSet.find((void*)this);
  if (iter != pNewSet.end()) {
    _isNewed = true;
    pNewSet.erase(iter);
  }
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

// a global static instance
static Object o;

int main()
{
  DEBUG(std::cout << o.isNewed() << '\n');
  // a static instance (local scope)
  DEBUG(static Object o1);
  DEBUG(std::cout << o1.isNewed() << '\n');
  // a local instance
  DEBUG(Object o2);
  DEBUG(std::cout << o2.isNewed() << '\n');
  // as members
  DEBUG(struct Composed { Object o1, o2; } comp);
  DEBUG(std::cout << comp.o1.isNewed() << ' ' << comp.o2.isNewed() << '\n');
  // created with new
  DEBUG(Object *pO = new Object());
  DEBUG(std::cout << pO->isNewed() << '\n');
  DEBUG(delete pO);
  // created as members in an object created with new
  DEBUG(Composed *pComp = new Composed());
  DEBUG(std::cout << pComp->o1.isNewed() << ' ' << pComp->o2.isNewed() << '\n');
  DEBUG(delete pComp);
}
```

Output:

```
std::cout << o.isNewed() << '\n';
0
static Object o1;
std::cout << o1.isNewed() << '\n';
0
Object o2;
std::cout << o2.isNewed() << '\n';
0
struct Composed { Object o1, o2; } comp;
std::cout << comp.o1.isNewed() << ' ' << comp.o2.isNewed() << '\n';
0 0
Object *pO = new Object();
std::cout << pO->isNewed() << '\n';
1
delete pO;
Composed *pComp = new Composed();
std::cout << pComp->o1.isNewed() << ' ' << pComp->o2.isNewed() << '\n';
0 0
delete pComp;
```

[**Live Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WwxFM0)

**Notes:**

1. The copy constructor and assignment operator of `Object` are deleted intenionally.
   Derived classes may provide a copy constructor but it has to call `Object::Object()`.
2. The sample doesn't consider other flavors of `new` (e.g. `operator new[]` or the align variants since C++17). That should be done in productive code.

Comment: There is also `struct S {Object o;};` and `new S;` `o` is not directly "newed", but indirectly...

Comment: @Jarod42 In our case, that was intended. Although, the member resides on heap it's parent class is subject of heap-management but not the member itself. To make this clear, I added the last sample in my `main()`. (`Compose` might be derived from `Object` as well if intended.)

Comment: Can I understand in this way: in you design, if an object is `newed`, this object is a gc root object? (ignore me if you are not intent to implement a gc library)

Comment: @reavenisadesk I believe so but I'm not very common with the subtleties of Garbarge Collector design. We came up with the above concept to allow our own smart pointers for non-`new` created instances. Thereby, referencing smart pointers may not delete an instance (when ref-counter goes down to 0) if it was not created by `new`. (Though, I realized some critical draw-backs meanwhile and wouldn't do it again.)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can prevent creation of objects on heap/stack.

1. To **prevent creation on stack** make the **destructor private/protected**:

   ```
   class heap_only
   {
   public:
     void release() const { delete this; }
   protected: 
     ~heap_only() {}
   };

   struct heap_only_deleter
   {
     void operator()( heap_only* p ) { p->release(); }
   };

   using up_heap_only = std::unique_ptr<heap_only, heap_only_deleter>;

   //...
   heap_only ho; // fails

   heap_only* pho = new heap_only();
   pho->release();

   up_heap_only up{ new heap_only() };
   ```
2. To **prevent creation on heap** make the **new operators private/protected**:

   ```
   class stack_only
   {
   protected:
     static void* operator new( std::size_t );
     static void* operator new[]( std::size_t );
   };

   //...
   stack_only* pso = new stack_only(); // fails

   stack_only so;
   ```

Regarding your edits, and **just for fun**:

```
void* pstart;

bool is_on_stack( void* p )
{
  int end;
  return pstart >= p && p > &end;
}

int globalint;

int main()
{
  //
  int start;
  pstart = &start;

  //
  int stackint;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha 
    << is_on_stack( &globalint ) << std::endl
    << is_on_stack( &stackint ) << std::endl
    << is_on_stack( new int );
  //...
}
```